# How to loosen the coupling for an implementation of a map maker?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, game-development

I want to create a simple dungeon crawler game in Java. The Main function can take an argument "-t" that says that the program uses a file to build the maps and the UI is characters printed to the application screen (and not using JavaFX for example). I want to make it so I can easily add other ways to make the map (like with a graphic mapmaker) and make the UI use some images, not text. the mapmaking using the file only needs the string path of the file. but other ways of making a map might not need a file for making the map so I can't use an abstract class with the getMap(String path) function that will be implemented in a concrete map maker class.

is there something I can write that will make it generic so the specific map maker will be able to get his arguments?

From what I can tell maybe a design pattern will be useful here but I don't have much knowledge of the subject, dependency injection perhaps?

here is an outline of the code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Map map;
        MapGUI mapGUI;
        MapMaker fileMaker;

        if(args[0].compareToIgnoreCase("-t") == 0) {

            mapMaker = new FileMapMaker();
            mapGUI = new MapTextGUI();

        }//other cases will be added in the future...

        map = map.Maker.getMap();
        mapGUI.print(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a factory to help create the map.